# Происхождение выражения "шиворот-навыворот"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло это выражение и что такое "шиворот"?

Comment: "шиворот-навыворот" пишется через дефис

Comment: Не этот вопрос дубликат того, а наоборот: этот 2012 года, а тот 2015-го.

Comment: @МаркИз: сделайте, пожалуйста, чтобы тот вопрос стал дубликатом этого, а не наоборот (читайте мой предыдущий комментарий).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я знаю, но на второй вопрос дан более качественный ответ, к тому же не самим спрашивающим. Этот вопрос был задан командой сообщества на заре проекта для наполняемости контентом.

Comment: Понятно, Марк. Тогда правильно, пусть будет так. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шиворотом на Руси называли широкие боярские воротники. Когда боярин попадал в немилость к царю, его сажали задом-наперед на тощую клячу, а одежду надевали навыворот.